# What is the difference between add website and add application into website while publish into iis

Tags: iis

While publish into iis i can create website and publish into it. And also i can create an application into a website. So can you please tell me why website and application

Answer (score 2):

In IIS Terms, a Website can have many applications.

Let's say you have 3 websites...

```
example.com
website.com
test.com
```

Those are all different websites, now lets say example.com has three applications

```
example.com/calculator
example.com/lightbulb
example.com/forum
```

Calculator, lightbulb, and forums are considered as `applications` under example.com `The Website`

Comment: Thanks Henry, It means i can publish into website or into application its up to my business. Is there any security issue?

Comment: Publishing is just pushing files and has nothing to do with security.